# Add images to a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, image, addition, horizontalscrollview

I want to create a HorizontalScrollView which reads the images from drawable folder. The name of the images are "image1" "image2" ... "image20". I don´t know how I can use the numbers to read them. Here is what I have:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.images);
   for (int i=1 ; i<20; i++){
       ImageView iv = new ImageView (this);
       iv.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.image1);
       sv.addView(iv);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in two ways.

First one is to create array with the id's of images you want to use and in your `for` cycle, just add the images to your layout:

```
int[] images = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, ... R.drawable.image20};
LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.images);
for (int i=0 ; i<20; i++){
   ImageView iv = new ImageView (this);
   iv.setBackgroundResource (images[i]);
   sv.addView(iv);
}
```

Or the second way, you can create something similar to this:

```
 for (int i=1 ; i<=20; i++){
   String uri = "drawable/image"+i;
   // int imageResource = R.drawable.image1;
   int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

   ImageView iv = new ImageView (this);
   iv.setBackgroundResource (imageResource);
   sv.addView(iv);
 }
```

I didn't tested the codes, but I think they should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use `drawables` without an array list, you can do this:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("Name of the Drawable", "drawable", "Your Package Name");
```

So your code will be:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.images);

    for (int i=1 ; i<20; i++){
        ImageView iv = new ImageView (this);
        int myImage = getResources().getIdentifier("image"+i, "drawable", "Your Package Name");
        iv.setBackgroundResource(myImage);
        sv.addView(iv);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of examples like this show building a list of your images first. And then you can use your code and iterate through the list.

So something like

```
List<Drawable> imagesToAdd = Arrays.asList(R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2, .... R.drawable.image20);
```

Then you can even use the foreach loop to iterate through this.

```
for (Drawable image in imageToAdd) {
  etc...
}
```

Comment: That is actually incorrect, as you would like to instantiate a List of Drawable elements there, but you are actually adding in resource IDs of the drawables.